# What is the Model in Flux architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, vue.js, vuex, flux

I'm a bit confused about the store in **state management system**.

I mean, if I would like to have an MVC architecture, is the store the model layer?

I'm using Vuex

Comment: The store could store model instances. It's not limited to that, though. It could also store data about if a menu is open or closed, what page number a user is on while going through a table, a selected theme color...  [A store is essentially a global reactive object which follows the normal Vue reactivity patterns.](https://alligator.io/vuejs/intro-to-vuex/)

Comment: Yeah, that why I'm a bit confused. If I was an MVC purist I won't use Vue since it looks like there is no clear separation between each layer (I'm coming from angular world). I don't really like the idea that my store (which one stores the model), get UI variables in it. IMO the goal is to have the most re-usable code.That won't be the case if functionalities are not clearly distincts

Comment: Well it doesn't necessarily have to be one big bucket, so to speak. That's where [modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) come into play. Reusable modules (section at the bottom of the page I linked) is important   in keeping with DRY principles. However, it's the reactivity of the store that make it so useful, imho. It can drastically cut down on the number of methods and properties in a component.